# JQuery to change a <map> image source when clicking and/or hovering over an <area> - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, image, mapping, hover, imagemap

I've created an image map using the basic `map` and `area` tags.
I've tested the map and all the areas behave as they are supposed to, so the HTML is definitely correct.

I am now trying to use JQuery to get the image of the map (the source) change according to the different areas when hovering and/or clicking on them. This way I am hoping to get a sort of 'interactive' map that shows how different places on the map are connected. 
All the areas I have defined have a unique ID.

This is the script that I am using for the click version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#area1').click(function() {
        $('#londonmap').css('src', 'area1map.png');
    });
});​
```

The #area id name changes according to the area that is hovered on, whereas the #londonmap one is the ID of the image used as a map, the source of which needs to change according to the area you hover/click on.

I'm not a JQuery expert, so I need to ask - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show just a HTML sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'src' is not a css property, but it's an attribute of the `<img>` tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#area1').click(function() {
        $('#londonmap').attr('src', 'area1map.png');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to change the image source with the `$.css()` method of jQuery. The image's source isn't set with CSS though, it's an attribute on the image itself. As such, you should use `$.attr()` to modify this value:

```
$("#londonmap").attr("src", "area1map.ong");
```